# Does iPad clear any earlier buffered audio, once i play a new audio?

Tags: javascript, ipad, html, html5-audio

I am trying to load and play few audio files in sequential order one by one, after user interaction (since only one audio file can be played at a time on iPad). I load all the audio files on user interaction and store them in different audio objects.
While playing these files, any file played previously can play again. In this scenario, audio is not getting buffered again when I call play on that object.
Is it a known fact the iPad clears all the buffered audio when it tries to play a new audio file?

Comment: I'm not aware that it specifically does that. What's happening, or not happening? You're not very clear on that.

Comment: i have a set of two audio files which i need to play one by one. i have created an array of two audio objects and i load both of them on single user interaction. since the audio is loaded, i can call play on them. Now the problem is this : Lets say I start playing the first audio, it starts buffering and after sometime it is fully buffered. At this point, i play the other audio (which in turn starts buffering when i call play() on that object). Now, after this, if I try to play the first audio again, it's buffered value returns 0. That means it will again start buffering. hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest looking at using a sound "sprite", essentially loading one sound file that contains all your audio (with gaps inbetween each) and jumping to particular points in that file. If you believe it is un-buffering after finishing you can always keep it playing a silent track within this sprite so you are continuously jumping around the one buffered track.

[Zynga Jukebox](https://github.com/zynga/jukebox) is an easy to use open-source JavaScript API for handling this, which allows you to specify at what time slots each "track" is and play each track on-demand.